# JSON return null in ColdFusion

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, fw1

I want to return a null as a part of my JSON response

```
local.JSON = { "pwdstate" : null, "pwdconfirmstate" : null, "content" : "" };
...
framework.renderData().data( SerializeJSON(local.JSON) ).type( "rawjson" );
```

But I get an error that says `Variable NULL is undefined.`

How do I send back a null?

Note: Non-existence is not an option

Comment: Have you tried `"pwdstate" : javaCast( "null", "" )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal `null` expression was [introduced in ColdFusion 2018](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2018/07/null-support-in-coldfusion-2018/). You still need to explicitly enabled it, either on server level (admin panel, Admin API) or on application level (`this.enableNullSupport = true` in `Application.cfc`).

You can work around it using [`javaCast("null", "")`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/javacast.html) for all versions >= ColdFusion 7 and <= ColdFusion 2016.